# Swift kernel in Google Colaboratory

Tags: swift, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I looked into the Files Browser in Google Colab and found the `/swift/swift-jupyter` directory:

[image]

Is it possible to change the kernel to Swift? I cannot find the documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We've released v0.2 of Swift for TensorFlow and it's running in Colab now.

You can follow the instructions at https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Usage.md#colaboratory to create a blank new Swift notebook.

There is also a tutorial in Swift (which you should be able to open in Colab by clicking the button) posted at https://www.tensorflow.org/swift/tutorials/model_training_walkthrough, and you can access other tutorials on the sidebar.

There still isn't a button in Colab itself for creating new Swift notebooks, though.

Comment: I run Ruby kernel with your help. https://dev.to/kojix2/ruby-kernel-in-google-colaboratory-32ni Thank you.

Comment: Is there any update to this since dev summit 19? I still don't see any menu option to create a "swift notebook".

Comment: Yeah, we released v0.2 of Swift for TensorFlow and updated Colab to run that. I edited my answer to include some instructions on how to use it.

Comment: @MarcRasi, any ideas how to run bash commands in the when the kernel is swift ? both % and ! don't work ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai see a longish suggestion in this post: https://forums.fast.ai/t/gentle-intro-to-swift-for-tensorflow/44311/12?u=marcrasi There's some discussion about adding a library that makes it easier, but I don't think any are quite ready to use yet.

Comment: Second link above is currently giving a 404. This might be the intended link https://www.tensorflow.org/swift/tutorials/a_swift_tour

Answer (score 4):

You can start using this link for now:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#create=true&language=swift